# java: как узнать, сколько памяти использует программа?

Tags: java

Есть задача: написать маленькую программу, которая запускается из командной строки, считывает данные из файла, расчитывает результат (площадь фигуры) и записывает его в другой файл.

Одним из условий является:

> Объем используемой памяти не должен превышать 16мб.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно определить, сколько памяти использует программа?

Windows, IntelliJIdea.

Answer (score 6):

Самое простое — вот так:

```
long usedBytes = Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()-Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
```

Результат в байтах (поделите на 1048576, чтобы получить мегабайты). Скорее всего задача подразумевает, что ни в какой момент не используется больше 16Мб. Можно просто запустить программу с параметром `-Xmx16M`, что ограничит максимальный объём:

```
java -Xmx16M MyClass
```

Теперь если вы не уложитесь в объём, программа просто упадёт с исключением `OutOfMemoryError`. В самом коде программы ничего дополнительно проверять не надо.

Comment: Спасибо! А где в коде это лучше размещать? В самом "нагруженном" месте, где создаются объекты в цикле, или в методе main(), или без разницы?